# All node's id are same with the last added node's id

Tags: c, pointers, struct, singly-linked-list

```
int add_server(Server *list, char *server_id, char *capacity)
{
    Server *new_node=(Server *)malloc(sizeof(Server));

    new_node->id=server_id;
    new_node->capacity=atoi(capacity);

    if(list==NULL)
    {
        list=new_node;
        list->next=list;
        return list;
    }
    else
    {

        Server *temp=list;

        while(temp->next!=list)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }

        temp->next=new_node;
        new_node->next=list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add some text to that code, describing the problem beyond the rather terse title ?

Comment: You don't allocate memory for `server_id` in `add_server`.  Do you allocate memory in the calling function or keep updating the same char array?  The latter will mean that all nodes point to the same `server_id` instance so will all have their ids updated.

Answer (score 1):

First, [please don't cast `malloc()`'s return value in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Second, the `return list;` is strange in a function returning `int`, that might cause problems. Clearly the function must return `Server *` (the type of `list`) in order to make sense. Or it could make the `list` argument have type `Server **` and re-write the caller's pointer, but that's often less convenient to use.

Third, you only copy the pointer for the id, so if calling this with e.g. a local `char` buffer holding different names, you will get the effect you describe. You need to make the id an actual array in `Server`, or call `strdup()` on the argument before storing.

So, either:

```
typedef struct {
    /* ... */
    char server_id[32];
    /* ... rest of fields ... */
} Server;

strlcpy(new_node->server_id, server_id, sizeof new_node->server_id);
```

or:

```
new_node->id = strdup(server_id);
```

Comment: It is cycle linked list. It means that the last node show the first node. I avoid using null

Comment: @user217895 Yeah, I realized, I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: When I change int add_server() to Server add_server(). compiler gives error

Comment: Thanks all, new_node->id=strdup(server_id) works. This problem is very important for me. Thanks